# Java Servlet (doGet) 204 Http erorr

Tags: java, servlets, jdbc

Hello all i have write this servlet to doGet data and Client-side can get some information from database after query and
pointer but when i send a pointer to servlet from client-side there
are no response and http code is 204 can any one help me with that?

> thanks

```
//This Servlet Make User To Get Data from Database (data) Table (replay) Fileds (Callreplay,State)
    package server;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


    /**
     *

     */
    @WebServlet(name = "GetStatus", urlPatterns = {"/GetStatus"})
    public class GetStatus extends HttpServlet 
    {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        /**
         * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
         */
        public GetStatus() 
        {
            super();
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        /**
         * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
         */
            @Override
        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
        {


            // getting id as parameter

            String strID;
            strID = request.getParameter("newid");
                                   System.out.println("* Pointer is "+strID);                   
                // connecting to the database
                GetStatusFromDB dbManager = new GetStatusFromDB();
                    dbManager.iniDBManagementLayer("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/data",
                                                    "root",
                                                    ""
                                                    );
                //System.out.println("** Connection with database OK!");
                // getting data from the database
                String sql = "SELECT * FROM replay WHERE S_id = " + strID + ";";
                dbManager.setFields("status", "comment");
                dbManager.sendQuery(sql);
                            String resp = dbManager.getJSON();
                            System.out.println("*** Mutaz Method Ok!");

                if(resp != null)
                {
                                    System.out.println(resp);
                                    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
                                    response.setContentType("application/json; charset=utf-8");
                    response.getWriter().print(resp);
                                   // System.out.println("Get Ok !");
                }
                else
                {
                    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_NO_CONTENT);
                }



        }

        /**
         * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
         */
        @Override
        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

    }
```

public void sendQuery(String query) {

```
   // Connection, statement, and ResultSet should not defined as instances
  Connection conn         = null;
  PreparedStatement st    = null;
  ResultSet rs            = null;

   try {
        InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
        DataSource ds =
        (DataSource)ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/jndipool");
        conn = ds.getConnection(); 
        st = conn.prepareStatement(query); 
        rs = st.executeQuery();

        processResults(rs);



    } catch (NamingException ex) {
      //  Logger.getLogger(DBManagementLayer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
       this.errorFlag        = true;
       this.lastError        = ex.toString();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
       this.errorFlag        = true;
       this.lastError        = ex.toString();
    }
    finally{
      if ( rs != null ) {
                           try { rs.close(); rs = null;}
                           catch (SQLException e) { 
                               errorFlag = true; lastError = e.toString(); }
                                }
```

Comment: You're getting the status code `204` (which equals `HttpServletResponse.SC_NO_CONTENT`), because `resp == null`. Is the `replay.S_id` field in the database a `NUMBER` or a `VARCHAR`? Also, it would be good to know what happens in `GetStatusFromDB.sendQuery()`.

Comment: S_id is an integer number in database,, i dont know why resp==null but i have been send parameter for it... thank you for reply

Comment: Things you can try: 1) Double-check that there is a row in the `replay` table with the id you're receiving at the servlet. 2) Remove the semicolon from the end of the query : `"SELECT * FROM replay WHERE S_id = " + strID;`. The correct way to use a `PreparedStatement` is to have a bind variable placeholder in the query (`"SELECT * FROM replay WHERE S_id = ?"`) and set the value to the statement using `st.setInt(1, myIntegerValue)`; you should refactor your code to allow this because the current solution is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: Thank you alot i have been fixed it and your notes was very good..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**in this line i most add

```
try 
    {    
        ////here most add rs.first();
        Gson conv = new Gson();
        String status        = rs.getString(fieldOne);
        String comment       = rs.getString(fieldTwo);

    String rep = conv.toJson(new StatusForm(status, comment ));
    this.statusAsJSON = rep;
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(GetStatusFromDB.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

this must add

```
boolean first = rs.first();
```

- and it will be fixed

  - thanks for evrey body here help me thanks for all programmers here thank you stackoberflow.com Max**

Answer (score 0):

Http response code 204 is what is being set by this line

```
response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_NO_CONTENT);
```

So it's likely that dbManager.getJSON() is returning null.

Comment: Hello marty thank you for ur answer.. so what i must do to fix this ?